# Movie with female protagonist that can travel a few seconds back in time

Tags: story-identification, movie

Looking for a movie,  released probably after 2000, about a woman that can travel back in time.

I think she is not the only one and eventually a group is after her, including her boss, who sets a few traps to see if she has that power, like inviting her to lunch and preparing the salt shaker to open in his plate, where she goes back a few seconds to stop him from pouring and tighten the cap. But a few grains of salt "slip through" and he finds one. The movie has a number on it like a route, as route 66 or 76, or a sports team like 49ers or 69ers.

There is a complex time related plot in her relation to his husband, who I think is investigating a disappearance that happened near a strange machine and there are yellow painted shoe prints where the disappearance occurred.

Any help will be appreciated, it has been bugging me for a long time.

Comment: *Aditya 369* had the number and a time machine, but no rewinding time that I can find.

Comment: Is this movie in English? What country did you see it in? Did you see it at a cinema, on TV etc.?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [*95ers: Time Runners*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1824904/) (aka *95ers: Echoes*) (2013)

> An FBI agent with time-bending powers must fight sinister forces from the future to save her loved ones from being erased from existence.

There's mention of a salt shaker in [this review](https://paullevinson.blogspot.com/2014/12/95ers-time-runners-original-and.html);

> *debris from events altered by time travelers showing up in the new timelines created - figuratively and literally grains of salt from **a salt shaker that lost its cap in an original reality but did not in a new, corrected reality***

Comment: Thank you so very much, that is it, it has been nagging me for some time, thanks again

Comment: @Ormazd - For the record, this film is ***awful***. You could use the 90 minutes far more sensibly. I'd suggest learning conversational Japanese, making a soufflés or reorganising your sock drawer.

Comment: @ormazd This is a bit of Valorum's usual humor, so please don't take it too personally.

Comment: I've seen it and agree 100% with @Valorum

Comment: Good to know-- from the premise and the details in this question I was tempted to go look for it.

Comment: @PlutoThePlanet - don't.

Comment: Sadly, i'a a completist for certain kind of sci-fi, i know it is a awful movie, but i have to have and watch it again

Comment: @Ormazd - I've long been an advocate of watching [Starcrash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starcrash) on the general principle that no matter how bad the film you're watching, you can always tell yourself, "*at least I'm not watching Starcrash again"*. This film, however, doesn't fall into the ' so bad it's good' category, it is merely bad.

Comment: @Valorum yeah, it's bad, nice concept, very badly explored. But now i know it is as bad as i remembered it.